# Insert Form data to MySQL in Php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form in Html like this:

```html
<!--HTML Form input-->
  <div class = "login-block">
   <form id="form1" style="display: block" method="POST" action="Insert.php">
   
    <!--Input link api-->
    <b>Link: </b><input type="text" id="link" name="apilink"><br>
    <br>
    
    <!--Chart Type-->
    <b>Chart Type:</b>
    <label class="custom-select">
     <select id="chartType" name="chartType">
      <option value="">Select</option>
      <option value="pie">Pie Chart</option>
      <option value="column">Column Chart</option>
      <option value="bar">Bar Chart</option>
     </select>
    </label>
    <br><br>
    
    <!--Button create chart-->
    <div class ="wrapper">
     <button type="button" name="create" onClick="drawChart();">Create</button>
     <br><br>
    </div>
    
   </form>
  </div>
```

I create a php file to insert what user type in form to MySQL Database, this is my Insert.php:

```
<!--Insert Form Data to MySQL-->
<?php 
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","123456");
    if (!$con)
    {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("activiti_report");

    if(isset($_POST['create'])) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO chartinfo (link, typeChart) VALUES ('$apilink', '$chartType')";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }

?>
```

But when I run my page, after type some text and choose drop down list, I press Create button and nothing happen.

UPDATE:

[image: My table structure]

Comment: You should sanatize the query

Comment: Are you sure you're passing a non empty `$_POST['create']` variable? Did you try and see if you enter the if condition? This is so easy to debug...

Comment: how do you retrieve this data : $apilink, $chartType ? NB you are open to SQL Injection, and mysql_query was deprecated

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I learn php for 2 days so I really don't know how to do it. I fixed like below answer but it still not work. :(

Comment: Your create button is `type='button'` so when you click you don't submit the form, you just trigger the js : `onClick="drawChart();`. Try with `type='submit'` (and use prepare statement, NEVER TRUST USER INPUT)

Comment: You haven't defined your `$apilink` or `$chartType` variables. Also, **avoid using `mysql_`** - use PDO or MySQLi, with *prepared statements*.

Comment: ok I fixed with that variables, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're open to SQL injection. I recommend you to use prepared statement.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create'])){
    $chartType = $_POST['chartType'];
    $apilink = $_POST['apilink'];
    $conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "123456", "activiti_report");
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO chartinfo (link, typeChart) VALUES (?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $apilink, $chartType);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}else{
    echo "Form not sended";
}
```

Comment: Which PHP version are you using ? And what doesn't work ? Do you have errors ?

Comment: I use php 5.6.8, nothing is happen, don't have any error in console :(

Comment: Can you insert this code at the begining to enable errors `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);` Can you also show the table structure with type ?

Comment: I updated my post. 
When I add your code, it say:  
Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\xampp\htdocs\script\chart_test.php on line 49
INSERT INTO chartinfo (link, typeChart) VALUES ('http://localhost:8083/timesprocinst', 'pie')

Comment: Why do you still use `mysql_connect()` ? Use the code in the answer and enable the errors for debuging

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are firstly not getting the data from the form.

To get the actual data you would need to get them from post like this.

```
$apilink = $_POST["apilink"];
```

Comment: I suggest testing by debugging.
Write this after insert into $sql line.

    var_dump($sql);

And look what is displays. Is it getting all of the data

Comment: INSERT INTO chartinfo (link, typeChart) VALUES ('http://localhost:8083/timesprocinst', 'pie')

Comment: That's what it say on my page

Comment: Add this line: if($result) { echo "Data added"; } after $result = mysql_query($sql);